# Ascending series of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that $H$ is an ascendant subgroup of $G$. Then there exists an ascending series given by: $$ H=H_0 \unlhd H_1 \unlhd \ldots \unlhd H_\beta = G$$ Is it true in general that $G = H_\beta = \bigcup \limits_{\alpha < \beta} H_\alpha$ or define the ascending series such that it holds?

This is certainly true if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

Comment: The first phrase is pretty misterious: do you mean $\;H\;$ is a subgroup of $\;G\;$ which is subnormal?

Comment: @DonAntonio $H$ is an ascendant subgroup of $G$. There exists an ascending series from $H$ to $G$. It is a generalisation of subnormal subgroups.

Comment: @R Thanks, maybe I understand a little better now. So I see we may have an infinite series here (of any ordinal). No question if $\;\beta\;$ is a limit ordinal, but if it is a successor then $$\;\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta} H_\alpha=H_{\beta'}\lneqq H_\beta\;$$ , with $\,\beta'\;$ being the greatest ordinal strictly less than $\;\beta\;$ ... This looks pretty straightforward, so I'll ask: am I missing something?

Comment: Looking at the definition of an ascending series in *A course in the Theory of Groups* by D. Robinson. We require a sequence of subgroups $\{H_\alpha \,|\, \alpha \leq \beta \}$ such that $G = \bigcup \limits_{\alpha < \beta} H_\alpha$. The condition must be imposed.

Comment: I have that book, and I cannot see any requirement that $G = \cup_{\alpha<\beta} H_\alpha$.

Comment: @DerekHolt on page 358. I am using the second edition

Comment: @R I've that edition of Robinson's book. That is condition (b) there. I am guessing Robinson means that in case $\;\beta\;$ is a limit ordinal, otherwise he'd just write $$G=\bigcup_{\alpha\le\beta}H_\alpha$$ otherwise I don't really understand. Only in Kurosh's book I remember a somewhat detailed treatment of these infinite ordinal cases.

Comment: I really don't understand as well. I'm am asking this question in light of proving results that require an ascending series. For e.g. Suppose $H$ is an ascendant subgroup of $G$, and I need to prove that $P \subseteq H$ for some $P\leq G$. I let $x\in P$, and consider the ascending series i have above. Then assume that $\alpha \leq \beta$ is the least ordinal such that $x \in H_\alpha$. My question is that why can we assume this? we had to have that $G = H_\beta = \bigcup \limits_{\alpha < \beta} H_\alpha$ for the assumption to make sense, otherwise any $H_\alpha$ need not contain $x$